# How to combine 3 arrays and remove the duplicates?

Tags: php, arrays

I have  3 arrays . I need to combine them using the Names as key, remove the duplicates (names duplicates ); only the most valuable must remain (high value based on the sales array). I'm wondering if there is any easy way to do this. All I have in my mind is several foreach operations which are boring.

```
  [Names] => Array
        (
            [0] => Adrew Watson
            [1] => Maria Jones
            [2] => Adrew Watson
        )
```

```
[sales] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12,000.00
        [1] => 11,900.00
        [2] => 11,800.00
    )

[time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 31-Jan-13    
        [1] => 30-Jan-13    
        [2] => 29-Jan-13    
    )
```

The output should be something like :

```
   [Adrew Watson]  => sales => 12,000.00
                          time =>  31-Jan-13 

        [Maria Jones] =>  sales => 11,900.00
                          time =>  30-Jan-13
```

I think it would be an associative array with the duplicates removed by "value" . Please note that the values of each array (e.g. sales ) is already ordered DESC

Comment: Not clear, Please show sample output that you want.

Comment: **STOP EDITING YOUR QUESTION TO BE COMPLETELY DIFFERENT! WRITE A NEW QUESTION, THIS TYPE OF VANDALISM WILL GET YOU BANNED!**

Answer (score 3):

```
// Assumed from your output the arrays have the indexes Names, sales and time
$names = array('Names' => array('Adrew Watson','Maria Jones','Adrew Watson'));
$sales = array('sales' => array('12,000.00','11,900.00','11,800.00'));
$time = array('time' => array('31-Jan-13','30-Jan-13','29-Jan-13'));
$new = array();

foreach ($names['Names'] as $key => $value)
{
    if (isset($new[$value])) continue; // if already exists, skip

    $new[$value] = array(
        'sales' => $sales['sales'][$key],
        'time' => $time['time'][$key]);
}

print_r($new);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [Adrew Watson] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 12,000.00
            [time] => 31-Jan-13
        )

    [Maria Jones] => Array
        (
            [sales] => 11,900.00
            [time] => 30-Jan-13
        )

)
```

As per your below comment:

If you want to remove a `Name` from the array you can do so **AFTER** running the above code by doing this for example:

```
unset($new['Maria Jones']); // remove Maria Jones
```

Comment: I think that what I need a multi-dimensional array

Comment: this can be done by loop .. and multidimensional array wait a second ill show you

Comment: great work ! thanks a lot Cryptic !

Comment: @DoingThings no problem, be careful with the way you are doing this. If the name array contains the same name, but in fact are different people with the same name you will run into problems where a duplicate for an individual may not truly be a duplicate. If you can use a unique id that would be the safest, and use it in place of the name.

Comment: unfortunately I just found that it has a major issue :  It removes the duplicates randomly . It should keep the highest ones and remove the others. E.g. in our example it removes 'Adrew Watson' with sales  of   12,000.00 and keeps  'Adrew Watson' with sales  of 11,800.00

Comment: @Doing Things. You only need to change the if condition for that. Change it to `if (isset($new[$value]) && $new[$value]['sales'] > $sales['sales'][$key]) continue;`

Comment: @cryptic ツ Well then I think then the questions needs a bit clarification. It said **"Please note that the values of "each" array (e.g. sales ) is already ordered DESC"**. What has OP failed to mention or notice is that if all three arrays are related to each other. Only one array can be sorted and then the other arrays sorted relating to this array. That is if 'names' array is sorted in DESC order, the new order of entries would be  [0, 2, 1]. And that would reflect in other two arrays. So needs to be clarified which is the primary array that is used for sorting.

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik, I'll assume Names is not ordered, but I can see Sales is and possibly Time as well. However, until the OP clarifies it's not advisable to edit someone's answer based on an assumption.

Comment: @cryptic ツ And I humbly apologize for that. I initially missed the line of sorting in DESC order in the question. I did not read it until your comment.

Comment: It seems that something else caused the issue. I tried to remove a specific "name" from the array using unset['$name'] and it seems that the whole array got broken because of this .

Comment: @DoingThings If you remove a element from any of the 3 arrays they won't line up anymore. They need to have the same array count to properly do what you are wanting. You can always unset() after you have run the above. See my edit.

Comment: Just curios why did is not accepted yet ? It matches your desired output

Comment: @Baba I think user is no longer active. OP had accepted then unaccepted when the above mishap occurred on his end and he never re-accepted. Correction, user is active last logged in a few days ago.

Comment: Some people are not just grateful .. after such a long conversation .... nice one anyway

Answer (score 1):

this can be done by [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)  than a[rray_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
<?php
$array1 = array("orange", "apple", "grape");
$array2 = array("peach",  "plumb","apple");
$array3 = array("lemon", "plumb");
$newArray = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);

$result = array_unique($newArray);
print_r($result);
```

[**Live example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bz89TN)

Comment: I need to have the "Name" as keys . not 0, 1, 2, 3. In your example it should be something like orange, , apple , grape instead of 0, 1, 2